# Is there a way to mock a web view in iOS by XCUITest?

Tags: ios, webview, mocking, xcuitest

There is a new webview implemented in our iOS app and I was wondering is there anyway I can mock it via XCUITest?

I already has mocking done for the native view but not the web one so I was wondering if someone did this before?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this mock?

Comment: I want to mock the login flow because then most of the test cases will depend on it and I don't want to make it depends on any network. but the problem now that the login flow is now inside a web view, not controlled by our iOS App code but from our backend.

Comment: @ayaAki - You need to create new mock login that's replace current screen. You can do many ways by introducing toggle that allow you can own by passing argument during launching time. It will open that login screen.